# Check for holomorphy of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex

Given a (rather complicated) function `H(z)`, what is the best approach to check symbolically whether it is holomorphic?

What I tried is checking explicitly the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)(*):

```
z = a + I b

H = E^-Sqrt[z^2] / (Sqrt[z^2] + Sqrt[z^2] Cosh[Sqrt[z^2]] + Sqrt[z^2] Sinh[Sqrt[z^2]])

HRe = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Re[H]], (a | b) ∈ Reals]
HIm = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Im[H]], (a | b) ∈ Reals]
HReA = Assuming[(a | b) ∈ Reals, D[HRe, a]]
HReA = Simplify[HReA, (a | b) ∈ Reals]
HImB = Assuming[(a | b) ∈ Reals, D[HIm, b]]
HImB = Simplify[HImB, (a | b) ∈ Reals]
Simplify[HReA == HImB, (a | b) ∈ Reals]
```

What I would expect as a result is either just `True` or some equation that `a` and `b` need to satisfy in order for the *CR* equations to be fulfilled. This would mean that my function is not holomorphic everywhere in the complex plane.

The problem that I encounter is that the call to `Simplify` does not complete computation in a reasonable amount of time (> 1 hour, then I aborted it).

Checking whether `HRe` and `HIm` are harmonic (which is a necessary condition for `H` to be holomorphic) did not seem to be any easier, with the second derivatives of `H` being even longer.

Is there a way to speed this up, or even a completely different approach? The derivatives are so long that a manual inspection is not an option.

<sub>(*) Note that as correctly pointed out by [murray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/148/murray) below, the Cauchy-Riemann DEs being fulfilled alone does not already imply holomorphy. Additional properties need to be given, e.g. continuity of H or continuity of its derivatives.</sub>

Comment: Do you mean one that completes or one that doesn't complete?

Comment: I'll try and see if I can find something...

Comment: Satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations does *not* suffice to make a function holomorphic! Simple example: `f[z_] := Conjugate[z]^2/z`, `f[0] = 0`; this is not differentiable at the origin, although it does satisfy the C-R equations there.

Comment: @Öskå Coming up with a really minimal example that gives the same issues is difficult for me, as the problem seems to lie in the complexity of the equation. At least I removed all unnecessary parameters and provided copyable example code, hope that already helps. I'll still ponder over a more minimal example, though.

Comment: @murray Of course you're right, thanks for the hint! My function would also need to be continuous. Would give +1 if I could.

Comment: Okay, apparently the square-square-root combination is what's causing the trouble here. If I replace Sqrt[z^2] by z above, I quickly get a result (namely, that my function fulfills the CRDEs). However, in my real application, I have more than just the z^2 in the square root, so unfortunately I can't accept that as a solution. Since I thought that the branch-cut of the Sqrt function along the negative real axis might be causing the trouble (and I know that H isn't holomorphic there anyway), I added an assumption "a >= 0", but to no avail. Does anyone have any further hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Since 2020 (after this post) Mathematica can now use `FunctionSingularities[
 E^-Sqrt[z^2]/(Sqrt[z^2] + Sqrt[z^2] Cosh[Sqrt[z^2]] + 
    Sqrt[z^2] Sinh[Sqrt[z^2]]), z]` to check for function singularities. The `Sqrt` in the result shows that there is a branch cut and so the function can not be holomorphic (as holomorphic functions have a finite number of singularities)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the `ByteCount` of `H` is ~630 KB, so `Simplify` will run forever.

```
ComplexExpand[
  With[{z = x + I y},
    E^-Sqrt[z^2]/(Sqrt[z^2]+Sqrt[z^2] Cosh[Sqrt[z^2]]+Sqrt[z^2] Sinh[Sqrt[z^2]])
  ]
] // ByteCount

(* 629392 *)
```

Here are two partial workarounds. I call these workarounds because it proves `H` is not analytic, but it doesn't *derive* it i.e. we need to supply guesses for where we think it's not analytic.

### Series

We can easily show `H` has a pole at the origin:

```
Series[E^-Sqrt[z^2]/(Sqrt[z^2]+Sqrt[z^2] Cosh[Sqrt[z^2]]+Sqrt[z^2] Sinh[Sqrt[z^2]]),{z,0,0}]

(* 1/(2z) - 3/4 + O[z] *)
```

### Plotting

We can visually see `H` has a branch cut along on the imaginary axis.

**Code**

Here is code to plot $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, dumped from my `init.m` file.

```
ComplexColorPlot[f_, x_List] := ComplexColorPlot[f, x, x, .5];
ComplexColorPlot[f_, x_List, y_List] := ComplexColorPlot[f, x, y, .5];
ComplexColorPlot[f_, x_List, b_] := ComplexColorPlot[f, x, x, b];

ComplexColorPlot[f_, {xmn_, xmx_, xdel_}, {ymn_, ymx_, ydel_}, b_] := Block[{myArg, myAbs},

  myArg[ComplexInfinity] = 0;
  myArg[z_] := Mod[Arg[N@z], 2Pi]/(2Pi);

  myAbs[ComplexInfinity] = Infinity;
  myAbs[z_] := Abs[N@z];

  Image[Monitor[

   Table[
    With[{tb = f[σ + I*t]},
     With[{hue = Round[{myArg[tb], 1/(1 + .3*#), 1/(1.1 + b*#)}&[Log[myAbs@tb + 1]], .000001]},
      List @@ ToColor[Hue @@ hue, RGBColor]
     ]
    ],
    {t, ymx, ymn, -ydel}, {σ, xmn, xmx, xdel}
   ],

   Row[{ProgressIndicator[#, {0., 1.}], "  ", Round[#, .0001], "%  σ + I*t \[LongEqual] ", σ + I*t}]&[1-(t-ymn)/(ymx-ymn)]

 ]]//Image[#, "Byte"]&
]
```

**Explanation of plotter**

Given $(x, y)$ in the Cartesian plane, this plots $f(x + iy)$. Looking at $f$ in polar coordinates, write $f(x + iy) = r e^{i \theta}$, where the phase angle $\theta$ is represented by color of the pixel at $(x, y)$ and the magniture $r$ is represented by the darkness of the pixel at $(x, y)$.

Red corresponds to $\theta = 0$, very light blue corresponds to $\theta = \pi$, colors between red and very light blue have $0 < \theta < \pi$, and colors between very light blue and dark red have $-\pi < \theta < 0$.

The darker the pixel, the larger the magnitude $r$. Pure white is a zero and pure black is a pole.

**Plotting your function**

Now plot `H` for `-2 < x < 2` and `-2 < y < 2`:

```
H = Function[z, 
     E^-Sqrt[z^2]/(Sqrt[z^2] + Sqrt[z^2] Cosh[Sqrt[z^2]] + Sqrt[z^2] Sinh[Sqrt[z^2]])];

ComplexColorPlot[H, {-2, 2, .01}]
```

[image]

So you can see the function's argument 'jumps' crossing the imaginary axis and probably has a singularity at the origin.

To see this jump, we can take a horizontal cross section of the above image:

```
Plot[Arg[H[z + 2I]], {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Since you're looking for symbolic methods, we can prove this is a jump:

```
Limit[H[ε + 2I], ε -> 0, Direction -> 1] == Limit[H[ε + 2I], ε -> 0, Direction -> -1]

(* False *)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that ByteCount thing? H would not seem extremely complicated to me on first sight, how could I know it is too tough for Simplify? That ComplexColorPlot is really neat as well as the limit calculation, thanks! (Of course it makes perfect sense that the branch cut along the negative real axis is transformed into one along the imaginary axis by the square.)

Comment: Anyway I'd still be interested in methods to check holomorphy for regions without branch cuts, i.e. Re(z) > 0...