# How to assume a function is holomorphic?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, assumptions

For example, for a holomorphic function $f(z)=f(x,y)$, it's well know that $\ln |f|$ is harmonic. I want to check it with mathematica with the following code:

```
FullSimplify[Laplacian[Log[Sqrt[u[x, y]^2 + v[x, y]^2]], {x, y}], 
 D[u[x, y], {x}] == D[v[x, y], {y}] && 
  D[u[x, y], {y}] == -D[v[x, y], {x}] && Elements[x, Reals] && 
  Elements[y, Reals]]
```

These code simply calculate $\Delta \ln |f(x,y)|$ and assume that $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+\mathrm{i}v(x,y)$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation.  It's expected that we'll get  a result $0$. However, I get the following

[image]

It seems that mathematica doesn't know Cauchy-Riemann equation implies $u_{xx}=v_{xy}=-u_{yy}$.  Then, how should I do?  How can I assume that a function is holomorphic?

Comment: Have a look here: [check-for-holomorphy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56049/check-for-holomorphy-of-a-function)